# 301 redirect get pagination

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to 301 redirect a paginated blog list from an old site onto a new url.

I think I'm getting pretty close with the RewriteRule but I'm not quite there yet, this is what I have:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=
RewriteRule ^(blog)?$ http://www.newdomain.com/news/page/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Using this rule if I go to

```
http://www.olddomain.com/blog?page=1
```

I currently get redirected to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/news/page/blog
```

I would like to be sent to

```
http://www.newdomain.com/news/page/1
```

I'm sure its just something small and simple that I'm missing.

**Edit**

Expanding on the solution below, I've added tags/category support to the rewrite rule using $1.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/tag/([^/\.]+)?$ http://www.newdomain.com/news/tag/$1/page/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few minor mistakes in your code.

1. You need to capture page parameter's value from query string first
2. Then use that capture value using `%` instead of `$1`
3. No need to capture `blog` since you don't need it.

Change your code with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/news/page/%1? [R=301,L,NC]
```